# Returning a Python dataframe (or other) into a Powershell datatable (or other)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, powershell

I have a lot of automation in Powershell but am trying to branch off into Python.  I have written some Python scripts and are executing them from PS, but have hit a wall where I am trying to pass arguments from PS into py, and return values from py back to PS.

My PS:

```
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM source
    WHERE the_DATE = DATEADD(DAY ,-1, CURRENT_DATE)"

$results = python C:\User\Python\Small_Data_Retr.py $qry
```

The py runs but then returns nothing.  The rest of my (functioning) scripts write to a SQL table so I'm in foreign lands on this.  My py wraps up this way:

```
def main(query):

    snf_conn = read_snowflake()
    try:
        pd.read_sql(query, snf_conn)

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Some error you don't know how to handle {e}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv[1])
```

The `read_snowflake` function contains the configuration for the connection, this all works.  I just can't figure out how to dump the `pd.read_sql(query, snf_conn)` back out to PS.  I've tried `return pd.read_sql(query, snf_conn)` and various other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that the problem is that Python wasn't feeding back to PS, so when I printed the dataframe I was able to capture it to PS variable:

```
try:
    dt = pd.read_sql(query, snf_conn)
    print(dt)
```

I can then parse the output in PS:

```
$vals = -split $results[1]

$vals[1]
```

Credit to Matthew Davis for attempting this last spring and documenting his steps.

https://matthewdavis111.com/powershell/call-python-script-from-powershell/

Comment: This isn't particularly flexible, when I want to pass full dataframes over to a PS datatable that will be more involved.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try to use the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.3#call-operator-) to execute your python script... something like this:

```
$pyCmd = Get-Command python | select-object -expand Source
$qry = "SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM source
    WHERE the_DATE = DATEADD(DAY ,-1, CURRENT_DATE)"
$pyScript = 'C:\User\Python\Small_Data_Retr.py'

$pythonArgs = @($pyScript, $qry)
$results = $pyCmd $pythonArgs
```

Comment: I'm getting an `Unexpected token '$pythonArgs' in expression or statement.` error, will look into the call operator more later